# How to apply Magic Weapon

Tags: dark-souls

Playing as sorcerer for the first time, I still use a melee weapon a lot. Now, I understand Magic Weapon spell adds magic damage for 60 seconds, but how do I apply it to my weapon?

I have a weapon and a catalyst equipped in my right hand (switching between them with D-Pad) and a shield in my left hand. I can cast Magic Shield spell and it works (shield changes appearance), but I am not allowed to cast Magic Weapon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wield your catalyst and your weapon at the same time: one in your right hand, the other in your left. Your weapon will stay enchanted even after you've unequipped the catalyst.

Comment: It works indeed, cheers. Pretty impractical though, if I equip the catalyst in the left hand, then I cannot use it together with a shield. I equipped another catalyst to the left hand (I have two), but now my gear is too heavy... Any tips how do people usually handle this?

Comment: @Martin You should be able to use the left hand catalyst to cast Magic Weapon on the right hand weapon. From memory, you don't need the catalyst equipped at all after the spell has been cast. This should reduce your weight.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to be equipping and removing the catalyst every 60 seconds. Well, I guess I will need more endurance after all. Thanks for help.